# Python lowering precision of zero

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, zero

I have a piece of code that is looking through figures that came from some calculations and are super precise and that code tries to figure out the right precision based on original figures (before calculations). Then it appplies the rounding using:

```
with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 5 # simplification for the sake of this example
    my_figure = +my_figure
```

And everything is great as long as my_figure is not equal zero. This doesn't affect zero at all, so it comes out with the same precision it had before (not 5 from this example).

```
my_figure = Decimal('0.0000...') # 0E-30, it comes from some calculations, not assigned like that
with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 5 # simplification for the sake of this example
    my_figure = +my_figure
    print my_figure # I get 0E-30, no rounding applied, I was expecting 0.0000
```

Is there any proper way of doing this the way that it affects zero as well?

Comment: `my_figure` is a `float()`, not a `Decimal()`. `localcontext()` doesn't apply to floats, only to `decimal.Decimal()` instances.

Comment: What's `my_figure = +my_figure` supposed to do? (is it meant to be `abs(my_figure)` or `my_figure += my_figure`)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is Decimal, sorry I wasn't clear about it.

Comment: @JonClements '+' is the same as http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.plus - it applies precision and rounding

Comment: @nirvanka Learn something new everyday - didn't realise it could be done like that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does [`Decimal.normalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) do what you want? It won't keep the precision as 5dp, but at least it will collapse the 0E-30 down to something sensible.